# Python using selenium -selecting form JS

Tags: python, selenium

After clicking "Advanced Search" on page https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/welcome#

I want to select :

1. Designated territories
2. Trade mark offices
3. Trade mark status
4. Application date

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample script which will click on `Advanced Search` button and select `Japan` from Designated Territories option.

SampleScript.py:

```
import Locators
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/welcome#'
driver = None


# Initialize Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

AdvancedSearchElement = driver.find_element(*Locators.AdvancedSearchElement)
AdvancedSearchElement.click()

TerritoryDropDownElement = driver.find_element(*Locators.TerritoryDropDownElement )
TerritoryDropDownElement .click()

TerritoryLabelElements = driver.find_elements(*Locators.TerritoryLabelsElement)

for elem in TerritoryLabelElements:
    print(elem.text)
    if elem.text == 'Japan':
        elem.click()
        print('Selected Japan')

TerritoryDropDownElement .click()
```

Locators.py:

```
AdvancedSearchElement = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#lnkAdvancedSearch')
TerritoryDropDownElement = (By.ID, 'DesignatedTerritories')
TerritoryLabelsElement = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.multiSelectOptions label')
```